# How to display unique values in PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to display unique customer values in array, below is the code;

```
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0)
    {
        while ($rad = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)){ echo $rad['customer'];}
    }
```

I'll be grateful if any one can guide me, how to display unique values?

Comment: Change your MySQL query to return only unique values (use `SELECT DISTINCT`)

Comment: Unique values of array $rad['customer']

Comment: Your current values looks like?

Comment: @MianOmerZia How does your current query look like?

Comment: @AmalMurali i want to use only array to display unique values not MySQL query

Comment: @AmalMurali $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_customer.$search_product.$search_pirority.$search_solution.$search_status.$search_category.$search_cause.$search_string;

Comment: query is being used for other multiple fields and data population i can not change the query.

Comment: you could always just add each value to an array, check if the next vaule is in that array if not print it and add it to the array else do nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL     query" '.$sql);


$customers = array();

if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($rad = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) { 
        echo $rad['customer'];
        $customers[] = $rad['customer'];
    }
}

$uniqueCustomers = array_unique($customers);
```

Or if you have a unique ID

```
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($rad = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) { 
        echo $rad['customer'];
        $customers[$rad['customerId']] = $rad['customer'];
    }
}
```